# Deploy two versions of the same wcf service

Tags: wcf, was

I have created WCF service and its deployed on IIS& under WAS with specific port.binding is the NetTcpBindig.

After we implement another feature to the service and deploy again with separate URL.

but our client wants us to have same URL with two different ports for two different versions of the service.

What is the best option to achieve this task.?

Comment: how about having an body element or soap header element as "version"? so you can redirect to different binaries by reading it first. this way you can even have 1 solution. how did you design it? please let me know about your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host both versions with different ports in IIS. You will have to create two different sites, but I assume you're familiar with that.